# What is the meaning of "partial cloaks"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *""partial cloaks"* in this sentence?

> *Partial cloaks* that work like sophisticated camouflage -rather like the alien in the 1987 movie *Predator* — might be achievable.

Comment: Please tell us the context for the sentence (where you found it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial cloak is something which hides ([cloaks](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloak#cald4-2-1)) an object incompletely ([partially](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/partial)).

In the movie *Predator,* the alien could make itself almost invisible. Here it is in a tree: the camouflage is good, but its shape can still be made out, especially if you know what to look for.

[image: Screencap from Predator showing the alien's cloaking]

Comment: There's a Wikipedia page on [cloaking devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking_device) which uses the word partially. Apparently some such things exist [e.g. video here](https://www.fastcompany.com/3036471/the-first-practical-invisibility-cloak-is-here), although nothing to match science fiction.